Shortcut(s) to access individual sidebar tabs
Is there a keyboard shortcut or combination of shortcuts to access individual tabs, such as the “View” tab in the Blender 4.3+ sidebar?

Blender 4.3 sidebar.
Individual tabs are locate vertically on the right.
Here: ["Item", "Tool", "View", "Screencast Keys" (non-default; depends on an addon)]
I wish there were combinations as follow:

N then I -> Item
N then T -> Tool
N then V -> View


No there isn't and no-one here works for or has any association with the Blender Foundation. If you want to suggest it, submit it on the Right-Click Select web site.

Got it! Thanks @JohnEason!
